# Find LETTERS-NUMBER pairs in postgres using regex

Tags: regex, postgresql, regexp-replace

I need to replace TEXT1-NUMBER with TEXT2-NUMBER.
Example "These are TEXT1-123 and TEXT1-456 examples" should be replaced with "These are TEXT2-123 and TEXT2-456 examples".

I can replace most of the cases using

```
Regexp_Replace(column_name, '(\mTEXT1)(-[0-9]+\M)', 'TEXT2\2', 'g')
```

But it also replaces some cases that I want to exclude, such as

- TEXT1-NUMBER-NUMBER
- TEXT3-NUMBER-TEXT1-NUMBER

How can I make it to match only exact pairs of TEXT-NUMBER?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(column_name,
                      '(\s|^)TEXT1(-[0-9]+)(?!\S)',
                      '\1TEXT2\2', 'g') AS Result;
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZQYALe/1).

Beginning with PostgreSQL 10, lookbehinds are supported, and you can also use `REGEXP_REPLACE(column_name, '(?<!\S)TEXT1(-[0-9]+)(?!\S)', 'TEXT2\1', 'g')` then.

*Regex details*:

- `(\s|^)` - Group 1 (`\1` refers to this value): a whitespace or start of string
- `TEXT1`  - a static string
  -`(-[0-9]+)` - Group 2  (`\2` refers to this value): `-` and one or more digits
- `(?!\S)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is no non-whitespace char immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: Thanks. It works in most cases. I found a few cases where it doesn't match, when the searched string is between parenthesis, quotes, or followed by commas or dots.

These are examples (TEXT1-123) and TEXT1-456, examples, (TEXT1-123), "TEXT1-3423", and TEXT1-895.

Based on your regex I tried `(\s|^|\(|\"|\.|\,)TEXT1(-[0-9]+)([\)|\"|\.|\,]*)(?!\S)` but maybe there is a better way. The string TEXT1-NUMBER can be anywhere inside common text.

Comment: It is Postgres 9.6.20

Comment: I tested in PostgreSQL 9.5, `SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(column_name, '(\s|^)TEXT1(-[0-9]+)(?!\S)',  '\1TEXT2\2', 'g') AS Result;` must work.